# How would I re add a notification request if I previously removed it from the pending requests?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, notifications

I have a reminder app and currently if I delete a reminder it also removes the notification if the reminder has a date or time associated with it which you can see in the LocalNotificationManager below. now I want to remove a reminder as well if the user checks off the reminder but doesn't delete it and you can see this in my reminderView in the ontapGesture I have but if they check it again setting it back to not completed I need it to re add the same notification request back so that the notification will go off. I have both the LocalNotificationManager and the reminderView code below as well as my reminder model. any help would be great!

Reminder Model

'''

```
struct Reminder: Identifiable, Equatable {
var title: String
var notes: String?
var date: Date?
var time: Date?
var theme: Theme
var iscomplete: Bool
var priority: RemindPriority
let id: UUID
//let filter: FilterType

init(title: String, notes: String? = nil, date: Date? = nil, time: Date? = nil, theme: Theme, iscomplete: Bool = false, priority: RemindPriority = .None, id: UUID = UUID()) {
    self.title = title
    self.notes = notes
    self.date = date
    self.time = time
    self.theme = theme
    self.iscomplete = iscomplete
    self.priority = priority
    self.id = id
}

/*var filteredReminders: [Reminder] {
    switch filter {
    case .all:
        return HomeViewModel().reminds
    case .today:
        return HomeViewModel().reminds.filter($0.date.)
    }
}*/

func formatDate(date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .full
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}

func formatTime(time: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    
    return formatter.string(from: time)
}   
}
```

'''

ReminderView

'''

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReminderView: View {
@ObservedObject var remindVM: ReminderViewModel

init(remind: Binding<Reminder>) {
    remindVM = ReminderViewModel(remind: remind)
}
 

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: remindVM.remind.iscomplete ? "circle.fill" : "circle")
                .font(.title)
                .onTapGesture {
                    remindVM.remind.iscomplete.toggle()
                    if remindVM.remind.iscomplete {
                        LocalNotificationManager().deleteLocalNotifications(identifiers: [remindVM.remind.id.uuidString])
                        
                    } else {
                        
                    }
                }
            Text(remindVM.remind.priority.name)
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(remindVM.remind.theme.accentColor)
                
            if !remindVM.remind.iscomplete {
                Text(remindVM.remind.title)
                    .font(.title)
            } else {
                Text(remindVM.remind.title)
                    .font(.title)
                    .opacity(0.7)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
     }
  }
```

'''

LocalNotificationManager

'''

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class LocalNotificationManager: ObservableObject {
@Published var deletedNotifications: [UNNotificationRequest] = []

init() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
        if granted == true && error == nil {
            print("Notifications are allowed")
        } else {
            print("Notifications are not allowed")
        }
    }
}

func sendNotification(date: Date, type: String, timeInterval: Double = 10, title: String, body: String, id: UUID) {
    var trigger: UNNotificationTrigger?
    
    if type == "date" {
        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute], from: date)
        trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
    } else if type == "time" {
        trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false)
    }
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [id.uuidString])
    
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    //content.badge = (notifications.count) as NSNumber
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id.uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    
    //notifications.append(request)
}

func deleteLocalNotifications(identifiers: [String]) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: identifiers)
}

}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Turns out I just needed to create another send notification request in the else statement in my reminderView. Under the onGesture in my reminder view I also added an if statement that contains the if else statements for the notifications to check that the notification has a date otherwise it would be pointless to remove a notification that doesn't exist.